# Assignment of Label.setLabelFor(Node) with custom control

Tags: javafx, label, custom-controls

I've written a simple custom control which extends `HBox` and contains a `TextField` and `Button`. As for many controls, it makes sense to have a label alongside describing its purpose, and I want users on mnemonic-capable platforms to access the control easily, more specifically giving focus to the button instance.

My first thought was to assign a focus listener to the custom control, on an assumption that the target node would be focused on label activation, but this doesn't work. On delving into JavaFX source, I find the `Label.labelForProperty()` uses a `NodeHelper$NodeAccessor.setLabeledBy(Node, Node)` method, but can't get beyond that as I can't find a solid implementation of the `NodeHelper$NodeAccessor` interface. My guess is that this utility class only maps associations with targets it deems suitable, and for some reason my custom control isn't.

My second thought is to open up access to the button, which can then be directly assigned as the target, but for obvious reasons this is a poor choice, and I'd far prefer to leave the button inaccessible.

Has anyone encountered this scenario and found a viable solution/workaround without compromising the visibility of internal implementation details of a custom control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple workaround that doesn't need your `Button` to have `public` visibility:

```
public class YourCustomClass {
    private TextField tf;
    private Button btn;

    public void registerLabel(Label label) {
        label.setLabelFor(btn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks; this is more or less the workaround I went with for my production code, but somehow still feels a bit "kludgy". Still, at least it works, which is the main aim, after all.